# Comparing value from object with string in PHP

Tags: php, string, object, compare

I'm comparing a string within an object to a string from a standard variable and even though they "look" the same when echoing them out, the if statement never finds that they match. Also, both values are text strings with no digits.

```
if($users[$x]->get_employee_id() == strtolower($employee_id)) {
    $found = true;
}
```

What am I missing here?

(I also tried the `strcmp` function)

Comment: `var_dump($users[$x]->get_employee_id(), strtolower($employee_id));`

Comment: @zerkms string(11) "abensouj " string(8) "abensouj"

Comment: yeah. the string length is different

Comment: @NightHawk The id from the object has that character at the end... get rid of it. If you can't edit the object, calling `trim()` might work.

Comment: @sachleen Yeah, I was just trying `trim` and it worked. Odd that it had whitespace in there. If you add that answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @NightHawk you shouldn't have to use trim though, it's odd that the id has a space in it at all. Does the user's id in the database contain the space? Or does the object append a space onto it after calling some method -- accidentally perhaps? Try to track down why the space occured, trim works, but it's dirty :D

Comment: @JordanArseno It was parsed from a CSV file, so it could very well be from there. I also don't have access to the source of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object: "abensouj " 
String: "abensouj"
```

The id from the object has that character at the end... get rid of it. If you can't edit the object, calling [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) might work.

```
if (trim($users[$x]->get_employee_id()) == strtolower($employee_id)) { ...
```